# Dynamic branch prediction miss count - incorrect

Tags: c, assembly, branch, prediction

I was looking over internet for some exaples about dbp and I found this one.
Source: http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/djimenez/614-spring14/bpexample.html (including solution)

Code:

```
main:
        leal    4(%esp), %ecx       ; function overhead
        andl    $-16, %esp
        pushl   -4(%ecx)
        pushl   %ecx         ; gcc stack alignment at the top of main

        xorl    %ecx, %ecx      ; i = 0 (%ecx)
.L2:                                       ; top of outer loop
        xorl    %edx, %edx      ; j = 0 (%edx)
.L3:                                             ; top of inner loop
        movl    c, %eax             ; %eax = c
        addl    $1, %edx            ; j++
        addl    $1, %eax            ; %eax++
        movl    %eax, c             ; c = %eax
        cmpl    $4, %edx            ; if j < 4 then goto L3
        jne     .L3                 ; INNER LOOP BRANCH

        addl    $1, %ecx         ; i++
        cmpl    $1000, %ecx      ; if i < 1000 then goto L2
        jne     .L2              ; OUTER LOOP BRANCH

        movl    c, %eax          ; return c

        popl    %ecx             ; function overhead
        leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
        ret
```

For a 1-bit predictor starting at zero, the result should be 2002. In my logic, there will be 1 miss at the inner loop (as it returns from the outer loop with prediction T), 1000x in total, and 1 miss at the outer loop 999x (because the loop will be predicted as NT from the inner loop end). That makes 1999, + 1 miss at the beginning. That makes 2000 in total.
I noticed, almost every time I'm about 1 loop off the real solution (in other examples too). I also tried to develop miss counter that checks every condition every loop, but it only confirmed my result (2000 or 1999 if predictor is set to T), so either I don't understand it properly or there is something wrong with my counting logic.

Could you please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

---

The asm was compiled from this C.

```
int c;
int main ()
{
  int i, j;
  for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
     for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
       c++;
     } 
  } 
  return c; 
}
```

Comment: How are you measuring this? Which platform? What's the 'miss counter' you've developed? :)

Comment: I like this question. As I understand the linked doc, I think there is a miss entering the loop and after leaving the loop. So `1000*2` for the inner loop and `2` for the outer loop. Hence the answer `2002`.

Comment: I have predictor variable. I trandformed it into do/while loops and at the and of every loop i check the while condition, if it's not as predicted, I raise misscount by 1 and every time change the predictor value. It's in simple c

Comment: @emmrk: They're simulating it in their head.  Only a couple real CPUs actually have dynamic prediction with only 1 bit of history, https://danluu.com/branch-prediction/ says DEC EV4 (1992) and MIPS R8000 (1994). Normally better to spend your BTB bits on 2-bit entries for fewer branches, if you're limited to a fixed size.  2-bit history gives you only 1 mispredict on the loop-exit branch for simple loops, not also on the first iteration like here.lists several real CPUs with 2-bit prediction, e.g. P5 Pentium, PPC604, and CDC Cyber.

Comment: @Koshinae but where is that miss coming from? It returns from the outer loop as T

Comment: @PeterCordes which is why I was so curious! Thought it was something like an emulated toy CPU

Comment: @emmrk (out of topic) reminds me of mipsIt :D

Comment: @emmrk: My concern is that real CPUs run asm, not C, and real compilers compile loops like this to `i=n; do{}while(--i != 0)` loops ([Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](//stackoverflow.com/a/47790760)), optimizing away the comparison before entering the loop body for the first iteration. So it's unclear whether the starting `T` for taken means "stay in the loop" (idiomatic asm loop) or whether it means "`if (! i<1000) goto end_of_loop` is predicted taken" (totally un-optimized C loop with an unconditional branch at the bottom and conditional branch at the top).

Comment: @Ecto: MIPS has a branch-delay slot which (on a classic 5-stage pipeline that checks branch direction in ID stage like MIPS I) is enough to fully hide the bubble from branches so no prediction is needed.  It's up to the compiler to fill the branch-delay slot with something useful, otherwise a `nop` is static.

Comment: @PeterCordes at the source link I posted it's translated into assembly, theres condition at the bottom of the loop...

Comment: @PeterCordes but in the software Im talking about can the delay slot be disabled

Comment: Then your question isn't a [mcve].  Don't leave out information that's critical for answering the question.  I understand branch prediction, and I understand C, so I assumed there was no need to follow the link for the assignment this was copied from.  Questions that depend on off-site links to not go stale are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well as I know c compilers compile for loops same as do/while, and the code can be written like this.

Comment: Okay I added the assebly to the postso everything is certain among weird compilers

Comment: @Ecto: If you'd compiled with `gcc -O0` (the default optimization level = none / minimal), it would *not* have compiled quite like this.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yep, same as some optimalizations would probably remove the loop as it's unnecessary, butthere wpuldn't even be difference in the result, except -1, which wouldn't make it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be analyzing for a 1-bit *global* predictor, with the state shared between both loop branches. (Or assuming both branches alias each other in the BHT.)  **But your assignment says to assume that the branches *don't* alias in the BHT.**

You're talking about prediction for the inner loop depending on what the outer loop branch did.  A 1-bit predictor uses 1 bit *per entry*, not globally!  That would be a bit too trivial.  https://danluu.com/branch-prediction/

More advanced real predictors do consider global vs. per-branch history, but usually with things like recording whether global prediction or local prediction did better for a specific branch, and selecting which prediction to use based on that.

---

**Your analysis unfortunately has mistakes even the 1-bit global state you assumed.**

In the first iteration, the inner loop branch is the first branch in the function, because the C is compiled to a `do{}while(--i)` asm loop (with some level of gcc optimization, but apparently not enough to turn it into `add $4000, c`).

Your analysis doesn't mention the first inner iteration of the first outer iteration depending on the initial state.  (And with separate state for both branches, also that the first outer loop branch accuracy depends on the initial prediction).

> There will be 1 miss at the inner loop (as it returns from the outer loop with prediction T),

The first 3 times the inner loop-branch executes, it *is* taken, so a `T` prediction is correct.  Perhaps your analysis was looking at the C abstract machine where there's an `if (!i<1000) goto loop_bottom` conditional branch at the top of the loop, before the first iteration?  Like you might get in un-optimized compiler output?

The final iteration of the inner loop mispredicts every time, predicting as taken when the loop branch falls through.  (1000 mispredicts).

With global state, then the outer loop branch mispredicts on all but the last iteration, so I think 1999 mispredicts would be correct for a machine with 1 bit of global state.

---

**For independent 1-bit predictors for each branch**

2000 mispredicts on the inner loop branch (1 each on first and last iteration of each inner loop = outer loop body).

2 mispredicts on the outer loop branch (1 each on first and last iterations of the outer loop).

The initial prediction=0 is not-taken, so we do indeed get a mispredict on the first iteration.